# charAt coming back as undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've got the following function, however it's saying the charAt is undefined. The error is relating to the alert line. If i do alert(value) it gives me the value no problems.

```
$scope.markAnswer = function(answerID, questionID) {
        if ($scope.containsObject(answerID, $scope.selectedAnswer)) {
            $scope.selectedAnswer.splice($scope.selectedAnswer.indexOf(answerID), 1);
        } else {
            $scope.selectedAnswer.push(answerID);
        }

        angular.forEach($scope.selectedAnswer, function(value, key) {
            alert(value.charAt(0));
            if(questionID == res){
                $log.info("questionID");
            }

        });
    }
```

The following error:

```
 TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at http://127.0.0.1:9000/modules/core/controllers/home.js:57:25
    at Object.forEach (http://127.0.0.1:9000/lib/angular/angular.js:325:18)
    at Scope.$scope.markAnswer (http://127.0.0.1:9000/modules/core/controllers/home.js:56:17)
    at http://127.0.0.1:9000/lib/angular/angular.js:10903:21
    at http://127.0.0.1:9000/lib/angular-touch/angular-touch.js:441:9
    at Scope.$eval (http://127.0.0.1:9000/lib/angular/angular.js:12811:28)
    at Scope.$apply (http://127.0.0.1:9000/lib/angular/angular.js:12909:23)
    at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous> (http://127.0.0.1:9000/lib/angular-touch/angular-touch.js:440:13)
    at HTMLDivElement.jQuery.event.dispatch (http://127.0.0.1:9000/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.js:4430:9)
    at HTMLDivElement.elemData.handle (http://127.0.0.1:9000/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.js:4116:28)
```

Comment: Is value a string? Check that please.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could try this one:

```
String(value).charAt(0)
```

I suppose that this is happening because your value is not a string and `charAt` is a method that returns the character at the specified index in a *string*.

Comment: thanks, it's strange because even when calling charAt() on a string, it evaluates it but in the console it still gives this error. However this has solved it.