# Why does response.chartAt(0) return undefined in my AJAX call?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, string

**WHAT I LOOKED AT:**

[charAt coming back as undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27777841/charat-coming-back-as-undefined)

---

**QUESTION:**

Why does String.charAt(0) return undefined in this case ?

How do I make it return the first letter of my response ?

---

**CODE:**

server

```
res.send("P This is a message"); //This is the response.
```

client

```
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/1/2",
        data: someData,
    }).done(function(response) {
        var message = String(response);
        console.log("RESPONSE: "+message);
        //Prints message without issue
        console.log("RESPONSE FIRST LETTER :"+message.charAt[0]);
        //
        //Prints 'undefined'
        //
        if (message.charAt[0] == "P") {
            localStorage.setItem("error_msg_local", message);
        } else if (message.charAt[0] == "L") {
            localStorage.setItem("success_msg_local", message);
        } else {
            localStorage.setItem("error_msg_local", "Internal error. Please try again.");
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using chartAt method as an array index accessor instead of a method, the correct use should be **message.charAt(0)**

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/charAt

Comment: Ahahahahah. Can't believe I missed that typo. Thx !

Answer (score 0):

There likely a code exists that suppress any errors thrown on your app. Since, [`charAt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/charAt) is a **method** / **function** exists on `String.prototype`, it should be invoked by using **parenthesis**, not square brackets.

```
// message.charAt[0]
// should be
message.charAt(0)
```